# Select by Location from multiple point feature classes

Tags: arcgis-pro, select

So let's say I create a buffer around a point feature class.
Now I want to select buffers that "contains" points from "three other/different/separate" point feature classes. It's not like "either/OR" but more like "AND" like that buffer must contain a point from all those three point feature classes.

I know I can use the "Select by Location" tool but I can only use one point feature class as input not only three.

How can I do this in ArcGIS Pro 3.1?

Comment: You could try a spatial join between your buffers and 3 point feature classes, OID only then select by attributes where FID_1, FID_2 and FID_3 have valid values.. I think rows that don't intersect will have a value of -1 but that would still mean performing 3 joins. Perhaps select by location of points 1, then change your selection method to *select from selection*, select by points 2 and then points 3, the remaining selected features will have intersected all 3 point feature classes.